# Are elements of Javascript arrays processed in a defined order?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
var a = [];
function p(x) { a.push(x); }

[[p(1),p(2)],p(3),[p(4),[p(5)]],p(6)]

a == [1,2,3,4,5,6] // Always true?
```

Is 'a == [1,2,3,4,5,6]' defined behavior? Can it be relied upon?

Comment: I think I understand your question now. The array literal `[[p(1),p(2)],p(3),[p(4),[p(5)]],p(6)]` is processed from left to right, so yes, after it is evaluated, `a` will be `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` always (for implementations that support `array.push()` of course). The result of the literal itself though is `[[undefined, undefined], undedfined, [undedfined, [undedfined]], undedfined]` since `p()` has no `return` statement, it will return undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are elements of Javascript arrays processed in a defined order?

Yes they are.

> Is 'a == [1,2,3,4,5,6]' defined behavior? Can it be relied upon?

No, the equals operator performs referential equality when comparing object.

Comment: In what way are "elements of Javascript arrays processed in a defined order?". The order that properties are returned by for..in is implementation dependent (and **is** different for various browsers). The only other "processing order" is the order that expressions are evaluated, which has nothing specifically to do with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: "Yes".

Longer answer:  Your question is actually about JavaScript statements in general and not Arrays.  The code you posted (`[[p(1),p(2)],p(3),[p(4),[p(5)]],p(6)]`) is not an Array, it is a statement that returns an Array whilst also populating an Array.  JavaScript statements are executed according to the rules of [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3ks45k7%28VS.94%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, what do you mean by "processed"?

```
var a = [];
```

That is an array literal, it assigns a reference to an empty array to a.

```
function p(x) { a.push(x); }
```

Each time push() is called, a new element is added to a at index a.length (i.e. it is always added after the highest index).

```
[[p(1),p(2)],p(3),[p(4),[p(5)]],p(6)]
```

That is an array literal that is equivalent to:

```
a = [];
a[0] = [p(1),p(2)];
a[1] = p(3);
a[2] = [p(4),[p(5)]];
a[3] = p(6);
```

The following expression:

```
a == [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

is always false, since arrays are objects and objects are never equal to any other object. You can do:

```
var a = [0, 1];
var b = a;
a == b; // true since a and b reference the same array
```

But

```
var a = [0, 1];
var b = [0, 1];
a == b; // false since a and b reference different arrays
```